# Execute command into Kubernetes pod as other user

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Docker allows execution of commands as other user with `docker exec -u`, when `USER something` in used in Dockerfile.
It is helpful to enter into superuser mode to debug issues, when you are running you `CMD` as system user in Dockerfile.

How to execute commands on Kubernetes as other user?

My kubectl version output is

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the spec schema to see what you can add in a pod or replication controller or whatever: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/spec-schema

You have runAsUser for what you want:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 41
```

Comment: `runAsUser` allows you to set the Pod's UID but it does not allow a different UID per `kubectl exec`.  As far as I know that is not possible.  If there is a strong use-case, please file a GitHub issue.

Comment: make sure not to use the `SecurityContextDeny` admission controller if you want to use `runAsUser`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported, but there is an open feature request for it: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30656