# File transfer inside kubernetes pod giving permission error

Tags: kubernetes, permissionerror

I am trying to copy a file from cluster to pod but it was giving me permission error so i transferred to tmp folder inside pod. but inside pod from tmp aslo it is not allowing me to move it reqd opt folder.please help

[image: error logs]

Comment: What happens when you change the permissions or use `sudo`?

Comment: you change the user inside the container if allowed else you can try with sudo if nothing works you can it with runAsuser config. else you can build new image with this image as base and change the with argument USER in dockerfile and that's it as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

When you create a container there is an option to set a user for this container if you or the maker of this container did it in the build process then you can encounter a situation like this 
Options to solve it:

- Check what the user you are running with and copy the file to this user `home` dir
- Check what the user you are running with and rebuild the image change ownership or permissions for `/opt` dir.
- You can rebuild the image and change the user to `root` (if this production environment not recommended)
- Also there is an option mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298062/9202256
  did't try it but should work.